# Rename partially multiple files in a folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have multiples files as follows

```
abcd_q1_2018.pdf
abcd_q2_2018.pdf
accc_q1_2018.pdf
accc_q2_2018.pdf
axxx_q2_2018.pdf
```

and a text file containing

```
abcd 1111
accc 2222
axxx 3333
```

now I want to rename above files as

```
1111_q1_2018.pdf
1111_q2_2018.pdf
2222_q1_2018.pdf
2222_q2_2018.pdf
3333_q2_2018.pdf
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the `rename` command of the util-linux package as follows :

```
while read -r source target; do
    rename "$source" "$target" $files
done < $mapping_file
```

Where `$files` should be a glob or list of files describing the files you want to rename (`./*.pdf` if all the files are in the current directory) and `$mapping_file` your file with the list of replacements.

The `read` command will parse each line into two variables we've named `source` and `target`. We use `while read ...; do ...; done < file` to parse each line of a file in that fashion, and we use those variables in the loop's body as parameters of the `rename` utility that searches for a string in a filename and replaces it with another.

If you have the perl `rename` utility instead of the util-linux one (check your `man rename` to find out) you can use the following instead :

```
while read -r source target; do
    rename "s/$source/$target/" $files
done < $mapping_file
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/cqTkL7)'s a sample run on ideone which uses the `perl` rename.

Comment: Please elaborate as I am new to linux.

Comment: @babun see [man rename](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html)

Comment: @babun I've updated my answer to explain the process in a bit more detail, please tell me if something is still unclear to you

Comment: @babun I've answered both those questions in my answer :-/ `read` splits line into fields (by default, around IFS, which work fine for your replacements text file) and assign their content to the variable it was passed as parameter, source and target. Yes, `$mapping_file` should correspond to your replacements text file ; you didn't gave its path or name so I used a variable, which you should value so that it points to the file

Comment: @Aaron Thanks a lot. The problem solved. By the way can you suggest how to self learn shell scripting?

Comment: @babun not really, I learnt on the spot which is far from great. I can recommend a few tools though : shellcheck.net is great for static analysis, it'll spot common mistakes and recommend better practices. Otherwise use `set -x`/`bash -x` to somewhat debug your scripts, it outputs expanded commands as it runs them which can let you pinpoint bugs; bit hard to read though. Good luck!

Comment: @Thanks for your response. It will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I like for loops, so here's some for loops!

Outer loop marches through the rename map, and inner loop applies the rename map to each file in the directory.

```
   IFS=$'\n' # So we can march through the map line-by-line 
   for key in `cat rename_map`; do 
      orig=`echo ${key} | awk '{print $1}'`
      new=`echo ${key} | awk '{print $2}'`
      for file in *_2018.pdf; do 
        new_file=`echo ${file} | sed -e "s/^${orig}/${new}/"` # ["] for variable sub
        mv ${file} ${new_file}                                # Rename it!
      done 
    done
```